# Proving a lemma related to composition of maps

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$A\xrightarrow{\phi} B\xrightarrow{\psi} C$ are linear maps, $\psi$ surjective, then prove $\psi \circ \phi$ is surjective $\iff$ $B = Im(\phi) + Ker(\psi)$.

I know $B/Ker(\psi)$ is isomorphic to $C$ since $\psi$ is surjective. Is $A$ isomorphic to $B/Ker(\psi)$ when $\psi \circ \phi$ is surjective? Also, how would that lead to $B = Im(\phi) + Ker(\psi)$? Thanks and appreciate a hint.

Comment: For the forward direction, start with any $v\in B$, consider $\psi(v)$ and use the surjectivity of $\psi\circ\phi$. For the backwards direction, try to get a contradiction by assuming there is some $v\in B$ but not in $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)+\operatorname{Ker}(\psi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it from definitions. Let $B=Im(\phi)+ker(\psi)$ and take any $c \in C$. We can write $c$ as $\psi (b)$ for some $b \in B$. We can write $b$ as $x+y$ with $ x \in Im(\phi), y \in ker(\psi)$. We can write $x=\phi(z)$ for some $z \in A$. We get $c=\psi (\phi(z)+y)=\psi (\phi(z))+\psi (x)=\psi (\phi(z))$ proving that $\psi \circ \phi $ is surjective.

Converse: suppose $\psi \circ \phi $ is surjective. Clearly $Im(\phi)+ker(\psi) \subset B$. Now take any $b \in B$. Then $\psi (b) \in C$, so we can write $\psi (b)=\psi (\phi (a))$ for some $a \in A$. Since $\psi (b-\phi (a))=0$ it follows that $b-\phi (a) \in ker (\psi)$. Since $b =(b-\phi (a))+ \phi (a)$ the proof is complete.